# Error when register database with ArcGIS server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, postgresql

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 (x32) and I have successfully connected to PostgreSQL(x64) as geodatabase.

When I try to register database with ArcGIS Server 10.1 (x64), I followed the instruction on the Esri' help. That is:

1. Download the x64 library for ArcGIS Server and copy to bin directory in install file.
2. Restart the ArcGIS Service
3. GRANT the database privilege to ArcGIS Server account

As I choose the connected sde database as register database, the error occurred:

**The connection property set was missing a required property or the property value was unrecognized. Cannot connect to database because the database client software failed to load. Be sure the database client software is installed and configured correctly.**

I am wondering anything else I should do to make this work?

Comment: Where did you get step 3?  That sounds like a SQL-Server Express instruction, not PostgreSQL. Enterprise geodatabases only require the privileges granted to a normal user (the same user with which the connection in the MXD was made).  You likely have a PATH issue, where the 32-bit DLL is found before the 64-bit one.

Comment: are you trying to direct connect? i.e. sde:postgresql:<your server>, if so make sure your database name is set. I have encountered this error message when trying to connect and required to install the library on the client side. This may not be a server problem, but a client problem.

Comment: Also just to check Postgres is by default listening only on localhost. If the x64 machine is your first attempt to connect outside of the database machine you have to enable its ip in pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 1):

did you copy needed files into database support folder in arcgis? 
etc : C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\DatabaseSupport\PostgreSQL

same issue i think:
https://community.esri.com/thread/68575

Answer (score 0):

Probabaly, you need to copy the files (libeay32.dll  libintl.dll 
 libpq.dll  ssleay32.dll) in the PostgreSQL route ("C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\postgisgui") to the arcsever bin route, then you can register the PostgreSQL database to the ArcGIS Server.

Comment: ArcGIS ships with the needed libraries for supported PostgreSQL databases. Clobbering the DLLs will not help, since the required ST_GEOMETRY support for 9.6 cannot exist in a 9.1 install.